# Add a new Column to a DataGridView control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with DataSource from a text file

```
If ouvrir.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then  
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(ouvrir.FileName)  
    While Not sr.EndOfStream  
        datagridview1.Rows.Add(sr.ReadLine.Split(CChar(vbTab)))  
    End While 
End If
```

Now I need to add another column from a database and I have a lot of problem with it.
While adding it show under the first column automatcally and what I want to add it as new column in the middle of the DataGridView.

My code its just:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select numero from database", cn)  
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)  
Dim dt2 As New DataTable  
da.Fill(dt2)  
datagridview1.DataSource = dt2
```

Comment: [DataGridViewColumn.DisplayIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex). Note that setting a Column's position in the layout of a DGV, doesn't change the Column's index. `Column(0)` will still be `Column(0)`, even if it's shown in another position.

Comment: If only you were actually using the `DataSource` property of the DataGridview, things might be easier for you. You needn't bother with manually setting columns except in special cases, and yours is not special.

Comment: how i can use datasource property?